# nagios bash script/command returning null

Tags: bash, nagios

I wrote a simple nagios command to check the change of a value over 1 second

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=$1
COMMUNITY=$2
OID=$3
WAITTIME=1
echo "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H $HOSTNAME -C $COMMUNITY -o $OID" > /tmp/csnmp_comand
VAR1=`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H $HOSTNAME -C $COMMUNITY -o $OID|cut -d"=" -f2|sed 's/[a-Z]//'`
/bin/sleep $WAITTIME
VAR2=`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H $HOSTNAME -C $COMMUNITY -o $OID|cut -d"=" -f2|sed 's/[a-Z]//'`
CHANGED=`/usr/bin/expr $VAR2 - $VAR1`
BPS=`/usr/bin/expr $CHANGED / $WAITTIME`
echo "OK $BPS|bps=$BPS" > /tmp/check_snmptest
echo "OK $BPS|bps=$BPS"
exit 0
```

And I wrote a service calling this script

```
define command{
    command_name    snmp_cps
    command_line     /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_cps '$HOSTADDRESS$' '$_HOSTSNMPCOMMUNITY$' '$ARG1'
}
```

When I call The script manually ( Even as the nagios user ) I get

```
OK 233|bps=233
```

Or something like that, but when I schedule this command it returns null and sets it to critical

Also My host.cfg is

```
define host{
    use     generic-host
    host_name   asa5505.customer.local
    alias       Options ASA 5505
    address     asa5505.customer.local
    _SNMPCOMMUNITY  SetSecurly
}
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       asa5505.customer.local
        service_description             Outside Interface PBS
        check_command                   snmp_cps!1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.16
}
```

With a few changes ( hostname and snmpcommunity )

Comment: Whe you call from the command line are you using the exact same quotation marks? The format off your check command syntax looks odd to me but I'm not sure that it is wrong.

Comment: I was using slightly different quotes And manually typing in the value's, I will give it a shot without quotes and with ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost the trailing $ on `$ARG1$`, so the OID is being completely ignored (Nagios will pass $ARG1 on to the shell, which will dereference it to "").

You should add some sanity checking to $1, $2, and $3 in the script to prevent this in the future.